# Expected Value for Powerball Lottery

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose that there the grand prize in the Powerball lottery is 150 million dollars and that you purchase exactly one ticket.  Calculate your expected winnings.  Assume no taxes, no split/multiple winners, and that the grand prize is paid in cash.

To play the game, we draw five balls out of a drum with 53 numbered white balls and one power ball out of a drum with 42 numbered green balls.  Anyway, I got the odds table here:

[image]

My approach:

$E[Winning] = 149,999,999 \cdot \cfrac{1}{120,526,770} + 99,999 \cdot \cfrac{41}{120,526,770} + \cdots + (-1) \cdot \cfrac{117,184,724}{120,526,770} = \$0.45$

But the answer they get is 42 cents.  The book gets $\cfrac{50,361,822}{120,526,770}$ but I got $\cfrac{53,703,826}{120,526,770}$.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong if anything?  All I want to know is if my approach is correct, I don't care so much about the numerical values although I checked my calculations several times in python:

```
149999999 + 99999*41 + 5000*240 + 100*9840 + 100*11280 + 7*462480 + 7*172960 + 4*972900 + 3*1712304 + (-1)*117184724)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that the description in the table doesn't match the current rules of the real Powerball game as seen [here](http://www.powerball.com/powerball/pb_prizes.asp).  Are you sure the rules and prizes your book is using match this table?  (Where did the table come from?)

Comment: @NateEldredge The table comes from my book.  The question asks you to refer to the section in which I pulled the table from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method looks perfectly good to me.

If I subtract 1 from all the prize values except \$99,999 and follow your procedure, I get the book's answer.  It may be the original table had the gross prize amounts (not counting the \$1 it cost to buy the ticket), and the author was going to convert them to net prizes by subtracting 1, but for some reason only did the first and last values.  As written, it's inconsistent in either interpretation.

You might see if you can find an errata list for the book that corrects this error; if not,  it would be nice to contact the author (or the publisher) and let them know of the error.

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge.  I checked the errata and it was not listed.  I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

For people who seem to be getting .411928 instead of .417848; it's because of a rounding error between the book and online version. The online version is referring to the question asked in this thread; as I have no idea where this question came from because I have different values for the Random Variables: instead of 41/120526770 I have 1/2939677.32. These are equal but there is one pair that is not. The variance from that pair causes the issue mentioned herein. Also, question in the book doesn't specify to find the Net... This is annoying. Please authors be specific.
[Here is my work:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpHFK.png)